# Adding .so files as dependency in a library module

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-module

I'm trying to write a android library module (using **Android Studio**). According to new project structure conventions, I've added all the external dependencies of jar-files to `libs` directory and `.so` files in `jniLibs` directory and adding this library module as a dependency to another UI-client module.

But i'm getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, i've already checked the apk file by unzipping it and the `.so` files were present in it, but still getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError`,

Comment: Does the error come at build stage or when running the app?

Comment: Post your error logs please.